# Calculating Date Difference in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to apply this solution to an Ember.js app. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3224854/2084924
It obviously works in the jsfiddle, but I am not able to implement it correctly in Ember.

I am learning, and probably making an obvious mistake. I've placed the function inside the model and am getting an "NaN" error. A date is passed through an input value in the format of M/D/YYYY. Anyone have experience with dates and ember? Can you see why it would fail to parse the date?

```
//app/model/task.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  taskname: DS.attr(),
  startdate: DS.attr(),
  enddate: DS.attr(),
  duration: Ember.computed('startdate', 'enddate', function() {
    var date1 = new Date('startdate');
    var date2 = new Date('enddate');
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
    return diffDays;
  }),
  banding: DS.attr()
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not reading the values from your model, you are just trying to convert the strings "startdate" and "enddate" to dates. It should be `new Date(this.get('startdate'));`.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  taskname: DS.attr(),
  startdate: DS.attr(),
  enddate: DS.attr(),
  duration: Ember.computed('startdate', 'enddate', function() {
    var date1 = new Date(this.get('startdate'));
    var date2 = new Date(this.get('enddate'));
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
    return diffDays;
  }),
  banding: DS.attr()
});
```

Comment: of course! makes perfect sense when someone else points it out. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
//app/model/task.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  taskname: DS.attr(),
  startdate: DS.attr(),
  enddate: DS.attr(),
  duration: Ember.computed('startdate', 'enddate', function() {
    var self = this;
    var date1 = new Date(self.get('startdate'));
    var date2 = new Date(self.get('enddate'));
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
    return diffDays;
  }),
  banding: DS.attr()
});
```

Comment: this works for same reason as above. I wasn't calling the value from the object. thank you.

Comment: There would be no need to assign `var self = this;` in this scenario. It's only needed if you want to reuse inside a callback of some sort (and even then an arrow-function would produce cleaner code).

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren yeah, i do it for being sure if any callback exist on function.but you right